# Python csv.reader is printing the last line a second time

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I have a 2 column comma separated text file of English sentences and their translation into another language with each translation pair on a new row e.g.

```
i like cats,me gustan los gatos    
hello,hola
```

I wanted to open that file and just get the second part of the pair (the translation) and have a list of those translations.  I have used the code shown.  However, the output is that the last item is always printed again at the end after the list, which I don't want.

```
with open('translate_outputs.txt', newline ='') as translations:
    translation_reader = csv.reader(translations, delimiter = ',')
    for translation in translation_reader:
        just_translation = translation[1].lower()
        translation_list = []
        translation_list.append(just_translation)
        print(translation_list)
```

Expected result:

```
['me gustan los gatos']  
['hola']
```

Actual result:

```
['me gustan los gatos']  
['hola']  
hola
```

Comment: could you also share the contents of the text file?

Comment: are you sure there isn't a print later in the code that does that? you are probably printing `just_translation` somewhere after the loop has finished

Comment: As the last comment implies, the code you show does not yield the output you show. Please show us either the complete, actual code or the actual output for the current code. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your snippet doesn't reproduce this behaviour. Please post a proper minimal **reproducible** example.

Comment: Also (unrelated but anyway): you want to create the `translation_list` _before_ the loop - else you keep on overwriting it on each iteration and will only get the last value in the end.

Comment: The subject is misleading – `csv.reader` isn't printing anything.

Comment: why a list is created while you always add one element to it?

Answer (score 1):

A shorted version of the code that give the expected output.
(I removed the appending to list)

```
import csv

with open('translate_outputs.txt', newline='') as translations:
    translation_reader = csv.reader(translations, delimiter=',')
    for translation in translation_reader:
        print(translation[1].lower())
```

output

```
me gustan los gatos
hola
```